# Grails - Display application message using TagLib

Tags: grails

I have a class in my my Grails (2.5.1) application with several string fields that need to be displayed on multiple pages. These change while the application is in use, so an admin user can go to the application admin page and change the messages. I want to use several TagLibs to display the messages.

The class name is appAdmin and the TagLib needs to query the field appName and if it == the correct appName displays the secMessage field/string.

Any help would be appreciated, I would post what little code I have but I think I mutilated a little too much to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try http://graemerocher.blogspot.in/2010/04/reading-i18n-messages-from-database.html to store messages in database and don't forget to cache table.